# Switch between tabs

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created a page with tabs container and when I click on the "**table 2**" card on the **TABLES**  tab it should open the **ITEM** tabs.

To achieve this functionality I have tried this:

1. created a page item to capture the value which was selected (eg: table 2)
2. created DA

   ```
    Event Scope: static
    Type: Immediate
    Event: change
    Selection Type: item(s)
   ```

   **True Action**

   ```
    Action: Execute javascript code
    Code: $("#TABS .a-Tabs").aTabs("getTabs")["#TAB_ITEMS"].makeActive();
   ```

but not working. Help me to achieve this functionality.

[image]